# Resources covering material of Cohen and Louie Condensed matter book (specifically with regards to computational physics)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, density-functional-theory

I need to study the contents of [*Fundamentals of Condensed Matter Physics* by Cohen & Louie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521513316) for grad school, but it's not very well written with regards to pedagogically or even logically motivating things (at least compared to Ashcroft & Mermin).

My research is in theoretical/computational solid state physics, so we are doing a lot of DFT, GW, BSE and I need to strengthen my fundamental physics knowledge, just to give a bit of context regarding what I need to learn this information for.